# Is /l/ in “whole” dark or clear?

Tags: linguistics, phonology, phonetics, sounds

Is **/l/** in 'whole' *dark* or *clear*?

I know that a clear (palatalised) /l/ is in a prevocalic position; nonetheless, I also know that the dark /l/  (velarised) is usually at the end of words.

Comment: Why don't you think your second paragraph gives you an answer?

Comment: @PeterShor hi and thank you for commenting! Well, because the / l / is both at the end of the word and in a prevocalic position

Comment: The "e" on the end of *whole* is silent, so it doesn't count as a vowel for this; "prevocalic" here just means vowels that are pronounced.

Comment: "Prevocalic position" refers to real pronounced vowels, not silent spelling letters. _Whole_ is pronounced /hol/, with the /l/ at the end of the world. You can't do phonetics unless you're dealing with phones. Letters are just distractions.

Comment: @JohnLawler thank you so much!

Comment: The word is pronounced a dozen different ways, and will even vary based on context coming from a single speaker.

Comment: @HotLicks Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Dark L or velarized L /ɫ/:** 
>   If the L sound comes *after* the vowel or diphthong in a syllable, it will be a velar or dark L sound /ɫ/.
>
> **The dark L sound is really two sounds:** a vowel sound + the L sound. After making the vowel sound, the tip of your tongue will rise up and press against the back of your top teeth in the same way as the light L sound. The dark L sound is a voiced sound, so your vocal cords will make the sound.
>
> *The dark L sound is often found in the middle or at the end of a word.*

**Examples:** Bell, hell, *whole*, doll, circle etc.

As John Lawler says:

> "Prevocalic position" refers to real pronounced vowels, not silent spelling letters. Whole is pronounced **/hol/**, with the /l/ at the end of the world. You can't do phonetics unless you're dealing with phones. Letters are just distractions.

The 'e' is silent in 'whole' and L is the final sound in the word so it's dark L (/ɫ/).

> **Light L sound /l/:**
>   If the L sound comes *before* the vowel or diphthong in a syllable, it will be a light L sound.
>
> When you make the light L sound, the tip of your tongue will rise up and press against the back of your top teeth. The light L sound is a voiced sound, so your vocal cords will make the sound.
>
> The light L sound is usually found at the beginning of a word.
>
> **Examples:** Like, laugh, long, lip etc.

[(Source)](https://www.really-learn-english.com/english-pronunciation-lesson-27-L-sound.html)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the accent, but it doesn't matter much because dark and clear /l/ are only allophones, not meaningfully different sounds in English.

In certain southern British English accents, "whole" would be pronounced with light /l/ before a word starting with a vowel, and with a dark /l/ before a word starting with a consonant.

In certain other accents, including some American accents, "whole" is always pronounced with dark l, even before a word starting with a  vowel. (My accent follows this pattern for the use of dark l.)

Dark, light (or clear), and palatalized versions of /l/ form a range, so cutoff points are a bit arbitrary. That said, English phoneticians usually do not describe clear /l/ as a "palatalized" sound.

Comment: One can but wonder about your *holy* and *holiday*.